# Axios POST request doesn't work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm using Axios to send POST request to Node.js server but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea how to resolve it?

My code is shown below:

`server.js`:

```
app.post('/registration', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

my class:

```
export default class Registration extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {}
  }
  handleSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    axios.post('/registration', {name: document.getElementById('name') }).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    }
  render() {
    return (<form className="registrationForm">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="required" placeholder="name"/>
      <br/>
      {/*<input type="text" name="email" required="required" placeholder="email"/>
      <br/>
      <input type="number" name="phoneNumber" required="required" placeholder="phoneNo"/>
      <br/>
      <input type="password" name="password" required="required" placeholder="pass"/>
      <br/> */}
      <button className="registerButton" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>register</button>
    </form>)
  };
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Are there errors? Is the console logging something wrong?

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: I mean it doesn't log anything in the console and the server doesn't receive the post request

Comment: Does your request reach the server? Do you see req.body being console logged? Do you see the network request in the chrome dev tools?

Comment: Are you using `body-parser` to populate `req.body`? https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: No, it doesn't reach to the server

Comment: Yeah, body-parser is already being installed

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi Are there any errors in chrome console?

Comment: @cdoshi it hasn't any error

Comment: Which port is the server running on? If it's not 3000, you would need to add a proxy in your package.json.

Comment: @MadhuBhat it's on port 3000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was for just a single line that I didn't write in my server side application.
The only thing to check is to put the following line after requiring the `body-parser` in your file.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have various problems in your code

- `preventDefault` is method. You need to call it
- I doubt you want to send DOM element to the server
- You want to handle network failure using `catch`

Corrected `handleSubmit` should look like this

```
handleSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // NB
    const data = {name: document.getElementById('name').value /* NB */ };

    axios.post('/registration', data).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    }).catch(console.error) // now you could see what the actual problem is
  }
```

Also it is generally not adviced to use DOM lookup methods in your React up. You should better keep a ref to the input.

```
<input ... ref={input => this.name = input}/>
const data = {name: this.name.value };
```

Comment: I dont think that ref is also adviced to use

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala "I dont think that ref is also adviced to use" why? Uncontrolled inputs are ok.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko It still doesn't work. The request recieved by the `server.js`  and `req.body` it's empty while it's not. and the error is in `bundle.js`

Error: Network Error
    at createError (bundle.js:607)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (bundle.js:219)

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi Could you plz add the error stacktrace. Also make sure you are using `document.getElementById('name').value` For example `console.log(data)` before sending it.

Comment: because the form element that is being used in particular case is in the data flow. And ref is designed to be used for anything that is outside data flow. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @YuryTarabanko as you told, I put `console.log(data)` before sending the request and it works. But it still doesn't show anything received in the server side. and the error is in `bundle.js` in   `request.send(requestData);` [image](http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00930/2p59svrg6k21.png "error")

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi Random guess: try to switch off ZenMate extension :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I've stucked in it for 4 hours and it doesn't work  no way :(

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi It is hard to say what causes the Network Error. Open the Network tab the might be some additional hints. Also have you tried to use a different browser?